# iOS 9 public beta focus bug

Tags: ios

I have the following code (Very simple). When I run this on iPad or iPhone running iOS 9 the keyboard doesn't show up and I cannot tap on field AFTER the first page load (Works first time). Is this a known issue that will be fixed? Where can I file a bug report?

```
<input type="text" id="test">

<script>
document.getElementById('test').focus()
</script>
```

Comment: You can file bug reports at bugreport.apple.com but in my experience they just ignore you.

Comment: _How_ are you "running" this code? You certainly aren't "typing" it into "iOS 9", are you?

Comment: Just made an html page then pointed Safari to it.  Try it yourself on iOS 9. You can click the field the first time (It should actually bring the keyboard up). The refresh and you cannot click the field anymore to get the keyboard to pop up.